# semantic-ui-react: Does large dataset in Form.Select makes the Form slow?

Tags: reactjs, html, semantic-ui-react

I am having below form(inside modal) created using semantic-ui-react.

```
  <Modal open={editBasicModal} size="small">
    <Modal.Header>Your basic details</Modal.Header>
    <Modal.Content scrolling>
      <Form loading={isSubmitting}>
        <Form.Group inline widths="equal">
          <Form.Input
            required
            label="First Name"
            fluid
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            value={values.firstName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            error={errors.firstName !== undefined}
          />
          <Form.Input
            required
            label="Last Name"
            fluid
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            value={values.lastName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            error={errors.lastName !== undefined}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.TextArea
          label="Bio"
          type="text"
          name="bio"
          value={values.bio}
          onChange={handleChange}
          rows={3}
          error={errors.bio !== undefined}
        />
        <Form.Select
            label="Country"
            name="location.country"
            placeholder="Country"
            value={values.location.country}
            onChange={(e, { value }) => {
              setFieldValue("location.country", value);
            }}
            options={this.state.allCountries}
          />
      </Form>
    </Modal.Content>
    <Modal.Actions open={true}>
      <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} >
        Update
      </Button>
    </Modal.Actions>
  </Modal>
```

The above code is from a component which uses Formik + yup.
`this.state.allCountries` is an array of 200+ records. Now this is making my form slow, the typing inside `textarea` and `input` are very slow.

As per my findings the large dataset in the `Form.Select` is causing the issue, because if i replace the `options={this.state.allCountries}` to `options={[ { key: 1, value: "india", text: "india"} ]}`, everything starts working fine. Or if I delete the `Form.Select`then also form works fine.

Few questions?

1. Is it a known issue?
2. what are the possible solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that this is a problem with `Form.Select`. I changed it with `select` and everything worked smoothly then. Here is the updated code for select:

```
<Form.Field > 
  <label htmlFor="location.country">Country</label>
  <select 
    name="location.country" 
    id="location.country" 
    value={values.location.country } 
    onChange={event => {
    setFieldValue("location.country", event.target.value);
    }}
  >
    <option key={0} value={undefined}>
      -select-
    </option>
    {this.state.allCountries}
  </select>
</Form.Field>
```

This renders similar(somewhat) select element with no slowness issue.

Hope it would help someone.